Google App Engine with load balancer to enforce TLS version, and multiple regions
I have a Google App Engine instance located in the us-west2 zone.  I recently added a load balancer to prevent connections using TLS versions lower than 1.2, for security.
However, when I look at the "network topology" in the Google Cloud Console, this is what I see:

This suggests to me that the load balancer is only active for traffic from the Americas, so people would still be able to connect from EMEA or APAC regions using TLS 1.0.  Is that correct?  Do I need to set up separate load balancers for each region?
Also, wondering why there is a line connecting the Americas directly to my instance, not going through the load balancer.  Shouldn't all traffic be going through there?

In the past, you could contact Google support and they would set your GAE to require TLS 1.2 and you didn't need to set up your own load balancer.  If that is all you need that would be an easier solution.

According to Google support, despite what the network topology diagram implies, all traffic from all regions will pass through that load balancer.
